# Merge jsonb rows of a column into json build object in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

[image: Refer here for the table]

There are three columns `id : integer auto increment , col_jsonb: jsonb , date: timestamp`.
I want to merge `col_jsonb` row values into json build object based on `date`,
the required output
[image: Refer here for the output]

Table:

```
+----+----------------+------------+
| id |   col_jsonb    |    date    |
+----+----------------+------------+
|  1 | {"Morning":10} | 2020-08-09 |
|  2 | {"Evening":20} | 2020-08-09 |
|  3 | {"Night":30}   | 2020-08-09 |
|  4 | {"Morning":20} | 2020-08-10 |
+----+----------------+------------+
```

Expected o/p:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| id |                  col_jsonb                   |    date    |
+----+----------------------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | [{"Morning":10},{"Evening":20},{"Night":30}] | 2020-08-09 |
|  2 | {"Morning":20}                               | 2020-08-10 |
+----+----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Why does have `{"Morning":20}` the id 2? In the input data id 2 is associated with `{"Evening":20}`.

Comment: id is an auto increment column

Answer (score 2):

Try This query:

```
select 
    row_number() over (order by date_) as "id", 
    jsonb_agg(col_jsonb), 
    date_ as "Date"
from 
    example 
group by 
    date_
```

`row_number` is added for numbering of rows if required

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1b23dde566ede09d14f32b9084d41105)